# How can I set read only property for Particular 'dr' in DATAROW

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I try to shown a particular row as a read only format for ListBox. But when  getting value from database I can't able to set the read only property for the particular row.

**C#:**

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("SectionId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("RegionalLanguage1", typeof(string));

foreach(DataTable table in dsPopularPrograms.Tables)
        {
            foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                var IsDisable = dr["IsPrabalamanavai"].ToString();
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow["SectionId"] = dr["SectionId"].ToString();
                newRow["RegionalLanguage1"] = dr["RegionalLanguage1"].ToString();                    
                    if (IsDisable == "D")
                    {
                        //Need to set the row as readonly

                    }
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

            }
        }
```

In the particular condition I want to set the read only property. I don't know how it is.

Please give some suggestion.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: I am showing a list of data in listbox but some datas should be in a readonly format in particular condition.Thats why Iam trying this

Comment: am using WebForms

Comment: There is no such thing as a readonly data row. Maybe you meant how to make it readonly in your UI?

Comment: But it looks like hard code right... I want to set the property as dynamically

Comment: Is there any chance  to set the property???

Comment: Try following : DataRow row = dt.Asenumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("IsPrabalamanavai") == "abc").FirstOrDefault();